# Scattering matrix ($S$-matrix), looking for a detailed guide to calculate it

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I cannot find a clear guide for finding a scattering matrix (aka $S$-matrix) in electrodynamics, from the very first steps to the final step.

What is the procedure to follow to obtain a scattering matrix if the polarizability tensor is known?

Will be thankful for any guides.

Comment: Do you mean a specific S-matrix element, or the full S matrix? It's not usually possible in practice to compute the full S matrix except in special toy problems.

Comment: Dear Andrew, in principle I need a complete scattering matrix. In my problem I have an incident EM field (E_{inc}) and I would like to no what will be the scattered field (E_{sc}). In principle, I keep in mind the relation: E_{sc}=\bar{S} E_{inc}, where \bar{S} transformation supposed to be a matrix and, according to my understanding, it is called as scattering matrix.

Comment: What is the incident wave scattering off of? A single electron? A large antenna? An aircraft? A layer of rock in the ground?

Comment: Dear The Photon, the scattering object expected to be a micro-object beyond Rayleigh approximation l\ll\lambda. Let the scatter has a cylindrical form and the incident wave is the plane wave polarized linearly along the elongation axis of the cylinder. Hopefully, I was clear enough.